# Codeigniter Infinite Scroll error

Tags: php, codeigniter, infinite-scroll

I try to make infinite scroll pagination in my codeigniter project. I'am using this tutorial http://www.mostlikers.com/2016/05/codeigniter-pagination-infinite-scroll.html to make it. But this is what i get
[image]

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>deals</title>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Custom Theme files -->
        <!--theme-style-->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />  
        <!--//theme-style-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Food shop Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
        Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
        <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
        <!--fonts-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!--//fonts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/move-top.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/easing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/imgslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/slideout.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.wmuSlider.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.wmuGallery.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="menu">
            <h1 style="color:white">Menu</h1>
            <hr style="color:white;">
            <ul>

                <?php if($tipeUser=="user"){?>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4 style="color:white">Welcome <?php echo $nama;?></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/my_voucher/0" style="color:white">My Voucher</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/my_profile" style="color:white">Profile</a></h4></li> 
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/logout" style="color:white">Logout</a></h4></li>
                    <?php } else if($tipeUser=="restoran"){ ?>

                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4 style="color:white">Welcome <?php echo $nama;?></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/dashboard" style="color:white">Dashboard</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/voucher_management" style="color:white">Voucher Management</a></h4></li>
                    <!-- <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/redeem_voucher" style="color:white">Reedem Voucher</a></h4></li> -->
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/logout" style="color:white">Logout</a></h4></li>
                    <?php } else if($tipeUser==""){  ?>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/login" style="color:white">Login / Register</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_voucher" style="color:white">Voucher</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_restoran" style="color:white">Restaurants</a></h4></li>
                    <?php
                        if($data_kategori->num_rows()>0)
                        {
                            foreach ($data_kategori->result() as $rows)
                            { ?>

                                <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/Type/<?php echo $rows->id_jenis_makanan; ?>" style="color:white"><?php echo $rows->nama_jenis_makanan;?>
                                </a></h4></li>

                        <?php } } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main id="panel">
            <header>
                <!--header-->
                <div class="header-in">
                    <div class="container">


                        <!---->
                        <div class="header-bottom">

                            <div class="col-xs-1">
                                <button class="toggle-button"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-11">
                                <?php echo form_open('home_controller/search_bar');?>
                                <div class="search">
                                    <form>
                                        <input type="text" id= "input-keyword" name="input-keyword" placeholder="Search ..." value="<?php echo set_value('input-keyword')?>" >

                                        <input type="submit" value="">  
                                    </form><?php echo form_close(); ?> 
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <!---->

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!---->
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="specials">


                              <ol> <div id="results"></div></ol>
                    </div>

                </div></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p style="height:10px"></p>
                        <div id="pagination" align="center" class="pagination-wrapper">
                            <ul class="tsc_pagination pagination" align="center">

                                <!-- Show pagination links -->
                            <!--    <?php foreach ($links as $link) {
                                    echo "<li>". $link."</li>";
                                } ?></ul> -->
                        <!-- </div> -->
                    </div></div>
                    <!---->

        </header>
    </main>


<?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')) :     
echo "<script>alert('". $this->session->flashdata('message')."')</script>";
endif; ?>
</body>

<script>
    var slideout = new Slideout({
        'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
        'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
        'padding': 190,
        'tolerance': 70
    });

    // Toggle button
    document.querySelector('.toggle-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        slideout.toggle();
    });
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    if( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) )
    {
        slideout.disableTouch();

    }
    slideout.disableTouch();
    // auto close
        slideout.on('open', function() {
            $( "#panel" ).click(function() {
                    return false; 
                });
            $( "#panel" ).click(function() {
                    slideout.close();
                });
        });

        slideout.on('close', function() {
            $( "#panel" ).unbind('click');
        });
</script>

<script>
    $('.gallery').wmuSlider(); 

</script>

</html>         
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var total_record = 0;
var total_groups = <?php echo $total_data; ?>;  
$('#results').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>Home_controller/load_more",
 {'group_no':total_record}, function() {total_record++;});
$(window).scroll(function() {       
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  
    {           
        if(total_record <= total_groups)
        {
          loading = true; 
          $('.loader_image').show(); 
          $.post('<?php echo site_url() ?>Home_controller/load_more',{'group_no': total_record},
            function(data){ 
                if (data != "") {                               
                    $("#results").append(data);                 
                    $('.loader_image').hide();                  
                    total_record++;
                }
            });     
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Model

```
public function get_allDeal_count()
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as tol_records FROM voucher v join restoran r on v.id_restoran = r.id_restoran";       
    $result = $this->db->query($sql)->row();
    return $result;
}

public function get_allDeal_content($start,$content_per_page)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM  voucher v join restoran r on v.id_restoran=r.id_restoran WHERE LIMIT $start,$content_per_page";       
    $result = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
    return $result;
}
```

Controller

```
    public function list_voucher()
            {
                if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
                {
                    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                    $data['nama'] = $session_data['nama'];
                    $data['id'] = $session_data['id_user'];
                    $data['tipeUser'] = $session_data['tipe_user'];
                }
                else{
                    $data['nama'] = "";
                    $data['id'] = "0";
                    $data['tipeUser']="";
                }
                 $data['notif'] = '';
                 $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/home_controller/list_voucher/';
                 $data['data_kategori'] = $this->jenismakanan->Getjenismakanan();

                $total_data = $this->voucher->get_allDeal_count();
                $content_per_page = 5; 
                $data['total_data'] = ceil($total_data->tol_records/$content_per_page);
                $this->load->view('listalldeals', $data,FALSE);
//              $this->load->view('listalldeals', $data);
            }

            public function load_more()
            {
                $group_no = $this->input->post('group_no');
                $content_per_page = 5;
                $start = ceil($group_no * $content_per_page);
                $all_content = $this->voucher->get_allDeal_content($start,$content_per_page);
                if(isset($all_content) && is_array($all_content) && count($all_content)) : 
                    foreach ($all_content as $key => $content) :
                         echo '<li>'.$content->id_restoran.'</li>';
                         echo '<p>'.$content->nama_restoran.'</p>';                 
                    endforeach;                                
                endif; 
            }
```

That's all the code that I used. I don't know what should I do to fix it.

Comment: Have you proved basic code is working at your environment i.e. exact code from linked page, without bootstrap and other extensions?

Comment: It didn't work. Actually, i confused is my code already right or not. @Tpojka

Comment: If basic example doesn't work, you have to change source of learning.

Comment: it's difficult to find it. Do u hv any reference? @Tpojka

Comment: Check examples on [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).